# Is repeated measures ANOVA appropriate for my experiment and is my sample size large enough?

Tags: repeated-measures, sample-size

I'm really confused. I never took statistics but am trying to read up as much as I can. I didn't think much about statistical analysis until *after* doing the experiment, unfortunately, but maybe someone can help me out.

I have 4 birds. Each bird must fly in 7 different wind conditions. In each wind condition, I measure things like wing stroke amplitude, flapping frequency, etc. ~40 times. I am pretty sure that those things are normally distributed. I would like to test whether the wind condition affects any of the kinematic variables I measure. The wind conditions I use are winds of different magnitudes and directions, so that 4 m/s and 3 m/s forward will probably cause greater correlation in kinematic variables then 4m/s forward wind and 4 m/s backwards wind. I hope this makes sense!

So, from what I can understand, it seems as if I should do a repeated measures multivariate analysis. However, I am concerned with my sample size of 4 birds. A plot of say, individual bird's stroke amplitude with wind condition shows an obvious effect (when it must fly faster, amplitude increases), but I just don't know how/if I can show that this is statistically significant. Any input would be appreciated!